# Boolean null values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with datatype string. I want to convert it to boolean using pandas.

The dataframe column has values such as:

```
'True'
'False'
'None'
```

I am using pandas to convert it to bool.

```
df[column] = df[column].astype(bool)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

I want to insert data frame to sql so I want the final result to be

```
True
False
null
```

How can I convert these values?

Answer (score 1):

If values are strings, you can use `map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['True', 'False', 'None']})

df['column'] = df['column'].map({'True':True, 'False':False})
print (df)
  column
0   True
1  False
2    NaN
```

For `None`s:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].map({'True':True, 'False':False}).mask(lambda x: x.isna(), None)
print (df)
  column
0   True
1  False
2   None
```

Another idea is use [Nullable Boolean data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html), not sure how working if write to DB:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[True, False, None]})

df['column'] = df['column'].astype('boolean')
print (df)
   column
0    True
1   False
2    <NA>
```

Comment: Failed to cast variant value "None" to FIXED

Comment: @Avenger All 3 types failed? `None, NaN, <NA>` ?

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['True', 'False', 'None']})
df['column'] = df['column'].eq('True').mask(df['column'].eq('None'))
```

Output:

```
  column
0   True
1  False
2    NaN
```

Or with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['column'] = df['column'].apply(literal_eval)
```

Output:

```
  column
0   True
1  False
2   None
```

Comment: I am getting Failed to cast variant value "None" to FIXED

Comment: I would expect `None` to work. What about using `'null'` as string? `df['column'].eq('True').mask(df['column'].eq('None'), 'null')`

Comment: Failed to cast variant value "None" to BOOLEAN gives me same error
analytics_df[column] = analytics_df[column].eq('True').mask(analytics_df[column].eq('None'), 'null')